# How to create entity with nested via LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I got one entity linked with another:

```
[Table(Name = "Employees")]
public sealed class Employee
{
    [Column(Name = "Id", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Phone", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, DbType = "Char(20)")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "UserId", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, DbType = "Int NOT NULL")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Association(Storage = "_user", ThisKey = "UserId")]
    public User User
    {
        get { return _user.Entity; }
        set { _user.Entity = value; }
    }
    private EntityRef<User> _user;
}

[Table(Name = "Users")]
public sealed class User
{
    [Column(Name = "Id", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "LastName", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, DbType = "NVarChar(100)")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "FirstName", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never, DbType = "NVarChar(100)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I want to create an employee:

```
var entity = new Employee
{
Phone = "Some",
User = new User
{
    FirstName = "Some", 
    LastName = "Some" 
}
};

context.GetTable<Employee>().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

And got this:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Employees_Users"

Is it posible to create linked entities in LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the [`OtherKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute.otherkey.aspx) property of the [`AssociationAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.associationattribute.aspx) as well. If not specified, it will default to the key of the related class, but in your case the names of the keys in the different classes are different (`UserId` vs `Id`).

```
[Association(Storage = "_user", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey="Id")]
public User User
{
    get { return _user.Entity; }
    set { _user.Entity = value; }
}
private EntityRef<User> _user;
```